# Fresh Ubuntu Install - No Wifi Networks Discoverable

Tags: drivers, network-manager

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my laptop, which is also running Windows 10. The install was successful and during the process I was able to connect to my wifi network with no issues (I can still do so when using Windows) - but now I can't see any networks at all when trying to select one. I can use a wired connection.

Using `sudo lshw -C network`, I get:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
   logical name: enp1s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: 80:fa:5b:35:06:d7
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.0.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:127 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df214000-df214fff memory:df210000-df213fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:df100000-df101fff
```

I thought it was maybe an issue with missing drivers because the driver is unclaimed, so I copied the driver for 8260 from [here](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) to `/lib/firmware`, but still nothing.

I've tried a couple of other solutions, such as checking for software updates and additional drivers, but so many are for previous versions, so I've found that they haven't made any change. The kernel version is `4.13.0-1015-oem` if that helps at all.

Results from terminal:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1010]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f1a5] (rev 03)

$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
[   15.839409] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   15.857552] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-    33.ucode failed with error -2  
[   15.857562] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857568] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857573] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857579] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857584] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857590] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857595] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857600] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857612] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857618] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857619] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[   15.857621] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-8000C-22
[   15.857622] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-8000C-33
[   15.857623] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: Let's gather a bit more information. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[   15.857605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857612] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857618] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.857619] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

We wonder how and why the appropriate firmware package is not installed. Please try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Check:

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep 8000
```

We hope you see:

```
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
```

If so, reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: You see in the output a "maximum version supported ...". Any way to force it to support a newer/higher version? I'm having problems with the firmware supplied.

Comment: @Andyc Please start your own new question.